# Как ипортировать из Mule Studio в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Существует страничка с описанием - https://github.com/machaval/mule-esb-plugin/ но даже после  создание пустого Mule проекта и добавления простого http:listener показывает последний как не валидный xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
                          host="0.0.0.0" port="8090" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <flow name="my-appFlow">
        <description>Example Flow for my-app</description>
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
                       path="/test" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <logger message="#[payload]" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```